# Ubuntu 20.04 Full Screen Mode Resolution in Hyper-V is very small

Tags: display-resolution, hyper-v

When I enter 'Full Screen Mode' on an Ubuntu VM in Hyper-V, it shrinks to a very small resolution that isn't usable. I've tried editing the /etc/default/grub file recommended in other Q&As without luck. I previously had the same issue with 18.04, so I switched to server and ssh'd to the VM; however, I would really like to get a useable full screen desktop going in Hyper-V.

Thanks

Comment: This link fixed the issue for the same issue I had with Ubuntu 20.04 on windows 10 with HYper-v https://www.donovanbrown.com/post/How-to-run-HyperV-base-Ubuntu-VM-full-screen

Comment: @RennishJoseph that also fixed my issue with Kubuntu 20.04 on Hyper-V. Worth copy-pasting that into a new answer?

Answer (score 11):

The `xrdp.service` is not starting because the address already in use.  There is an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/linux-vm-tools/issues/94) about this on github.

To solve this:

First, get the scripts from GitHub:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/linux-vm-tools.git ~/linux-vm-tools
cd ~/linux-vm-tools/ubuntu/18.04/
```

Then, make the scripts executable and run them...

```
sudo chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
sudo reboot
cd ~/linux-vm-tools/ubuntu/18.04/
sudo ./install.sh
sudo systemctl enable xrdp.service
```

Open `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` for editing:

```
sudo gedit /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

add these two lines (or change them if present):

```
port=vsock://-1:3389
use_vsock=false
```

restart the service and system:

```
sudo xrdp restart
sudo shutdown -h 0
```

On Windows Powershell with Admin Privileges, run the command:

```
Set-VM -VMName <your_vm_name>  -EnhancedSessionTransportType HvSocket
```

*This solution is adapted from the [Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/virtualization/sneak-peek-taking-a-spin-with-enhanced-linux-vms/ba-p/382415) and a post on [medium.com](https://medium.com/@labappengineering/ubuntu-20-04-on-hyper-v-8888fe3ced64)*

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 20.10 but I get a black screen after login attempt with Xorg protocol.  I'll have to re-install the vm now in order to get into it and this time I will also install Xvnc as a backup.

Comment: This worked for me. The key part here (not found in the answer here but found in the medium.com link) is to create the VM using generation 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these steps:

- Edit Grub

  ```
   sudo vi /etc/default/grub
  ```

  to modify the resolution during boot
- Modify

  ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"
  ```
- Modify

  ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"
  ```
- Save
- Update grub with

  ```
   sudo update-grub
  ```
- Reboot

Answer (score 0):

I tried different things to get the login dialog with the possibility to adjust the screen resolution. After a new installation of Ubuntu with the predefined Hyper-V package, it worked initially. At some point after that, however, not anymore. It was really annoying. But now I've discovered a possibility that always works for me.

- Shut down Ubuntu closing the remote connection.
- Deactivate the guest services for the VM at the integration services.
- Start Ubuntu without guest services.
- Quit Ubuntu again and close remote connection.
- Activate the guest services again.
- Start VM and connect and voila, the login dialog with the option to select the screen resolution is back.